# Do I need to consider shunt admittance for line losses doing load flows?

Tags: transmission-line, loss

If I have a long transmission line (Pi model) the current just go through the equivalent impedance of the line, but I've seen demonstrations that include this shunt admittance as if the current flows through them as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the problem isn't well defined, and it's not clear what the question is asking, beyond a trivial "yes" that does not fit into the answer box.

Answer (score 0):

The line carrying current at the high voltage does cause a capacitive effect with respect to ground. The value of capacitance differs from place to place depending on various factors. Having said that, considering the capacitor charging current (shunt losses) may add up accuracy in measurement of line losses. The charging current is many times negligible considering the power line frequency at which the line operates and in scenarios where line losses are calculated for a short line length.